# What's the meaning of "spin-off"?

Tags: meaning

What's the meanining of spin-off? like the spin-off of a TV series.

Comment: Have you tried looking it up?

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> In media, a [spin-off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-off_(media)) is a radio program, television program, video game, or any narrative work, derived from one or more already existing works, that focuses, in particular, in more detail on one aspect of that original work (e.g. a particular topic, character, or event).

More information about spin-offs (including plenty of examples) can be found at the [full article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-off_(media)).

Answer (score 0):

A spin-off is a new television show that retains some elements of an original show.

For example:  a secondary character on one show may become the main character of a new show.

A classic (American) example would be [*The Jeffersons*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jeffersons) spun off of *All in the Family*. George Jefferson appeared as a character on All in the Family, and then he was given his own show which was only distantly related to the original.

Another way of stating this:  the shows share the same universe.   This is common with spin-offs of Sci-Fi or Fantasy series.  (See [Xena: Warrior Princess](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xena%3a_Warrior_Princess) and Hercules:  The Legendary Journeys.)

Answer (score 0):

Both other answers are entirely correct. However, please note that spin-offs aren't necessarily limited to TV shows, movies or video games. Spin-offs can also refer to companies, organisations or products.

Be it a movie, a game or a company, a spin-off will have the same people, places, themes or ideas as the original. (taken from [Wikipedia's Simple English definition](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-off))

Comment: The asker explicitly noted that they were looking for "spin-off" as it related to TV series. But yes, you are correct in noting that "spin-off" has other meanings and uses.

Comment: @MrHen Yes, I know. This was just extra info, don't expect my answer to be accepted as the best one. :)